# How to statistically categorize a list of reasons?

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, dataset

I am working with call center data, one of the variables available is "Reason" which is a description of the reason the customer called. There is 40 different reasons that the agent can choose from. There is also a customer satisfaction field that is binary of yes/no. I want to use statistics to categorize these reasons (40) into around 5 categories based on their effect on customer satisfaction. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate the data per category.

Compute the probability for each category.

Sort.

Plot.

Choose where to split the data. It's just 40 points, no need to rely on algorithms to magically do what you can do in 1 minute by hand.

Comment: Thank you. 1-What if the probabilities are very close to each other? 2-What if I had more than 40, what statistic would you use?
3-How do you calculate probability you are suggesting? is it number of customers satisfied given that reason divided by number of customers not satisfied given that reason, or do you divide that by total number of all customer who are satisfied?

Comment: If they are really close, do not rely on the algorithms to make an educated guess... If it is 40000, it would still be one-dimensional, but then you might consider using density estimation. Frequency.